# Why isn't this shell command giving the desired result?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am using the **wkhtmtoimage** library on my server, and I have managed to get the output for the following command when I am running in PuTTY:

```
wkhtmltoimage www.google.com test.jpg
```

But, when I use the following shell command I don't get the output, and I don't know why.

```
$filnename = "test.jpg";
$url = "http://www.google.com";    
shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage $url $filename");
```

Even I tried with this variation instead, but still without getting the desired result:

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage $url $filename");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I downloaded  the Linux binary  and put it into the folder then I ran it.Whether I need to restart the server the changes affected?

shell_exec command is allowed because we used it for ffmpeg(already installed one)

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` at the end of your command to catch error messages

Comment: Small notice, the domain in your PHP scripts differs from the one in your SSH (notice the http:// in your PHP script..)

Comment: @Dogbert  I didnt get any errors

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give an exact solution but if you can try out what I write I might be of help. I will list more solutions if the one I am providing does not work.

**Solution proposal 1:**
Use quotes around url and filename

```
shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage \"$url\" \"$filename\"");
```

**Solution proposal 2:**
Try redirecting streams to files and type the contents.

```
shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage \"$url\" \"$filename\" > output.txt 2> error.txt");
```

Comment: where I need to check that error.txt file.Now also i didnt get any images.

Comment: just read the contents from the shell, or use echo file_get_contents("error.txt"); same goes for output as well. just check if they have any useful info in them.

Comment: echo file_get_contents("error.txt"); it shows me a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

May be user under which PHP (or Apache) runs have no permissions to run this tool. Try printing output of this command or just use `passthru()` to directly print output of command.
Another solution is to pass output to files as @Cem_Kalyoncu wrote.

Comment: didnt show anything on the page.Any idea?Struggling for a day I cant find the mistake.

Comment: May be wkhtmltoimage don`t have permissions to create files or write to files in directory where your PHP script is?

Comment: But if I use putty it can able to write the files.So is there any difference using between putty and script.I hope it not like that.I get the files in root folder if I use putty.

Comment: Yes, it is big difference, because your putty connects using different user than PHP script uses

Comment: But I gave the permission chmod(0777).Eventhough is it affect? How can i give the permission to all user?Then If I install using linux command whether it will work instead of putting the binary into the folder.IS there any solution

Comment: @Timur How can I set the permission to the pertaining user? I'm having the exact same problem and error is 'Error: Could not write to output file Error: Could not save image". So it must be this. How can I find which user the PHP is using and how do I set permission?

Comment: @user1715366 If you are runing PHP under Apache, it will use apache's user. You can find what user under it is executing using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as Then, you should use `chown` tool to change owner and/or group of the folder to that apache uses. If you are not familiar to all this, you can just assign `777` permission to folder (all permissions to all), but this is a security issue in some conditions. But if you already have such file and don't need to create new, it would be better to assign permissions only to this file